# BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile missing in Reaper DAW v6.73

Tags: lua, midi, reaper

I am evaluating Reaper for automatic music production. "Automatic" like "no human interaction". According to what I have learned in my research, it seems to be possible.

Currently I am stuck. A vital part of my work is importing MIDI files. According to the API one way to do this is the function `BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile`. When I call it, I get this error:

```
attempt to call a nil value (field 'BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile')
```

Which tells me that the method is not defined. I wrote a simple test to verify that:

```
reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Reaper version: " .. reaper.GetAppVersion() .. "\n")
if reaper.BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile == nil then
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile does not exist.\n")
else
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile exists.\n")
end
if reaper.BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile2 == nil then
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile2 does not exist.\n")
else
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile2 exists.\n")
end
if reaper.ShowConsoleMsg == nil then
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method ShowConsoleMsg does not exist.\n")
else
    reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Method ShowConsoleMsg exists.\n")
end
```

The output in the Reaper console is:

```
Reaper version: 6.73/macOS-arm64
Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile does not exist.
Method BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile2 does not exist.
Method ShowConsoleMsg exists.
```

I am sure that I missed something here. Any help would be appreciated.

I called the method `BR_SetTakeSourceFromFile` and expected it to work as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you just need to install the "SWS extensions". Case closed!